# If $f(z)$ is defined in the unit disk such that both $f^2(z)$ and $f^3(z)$ are analytic in the disk. Is $f(z)$ analytic in the disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

If $f(z)$ is defined in the unit disk such that both $f^2(z)$ and $f^3(z)$ are analytic in the disk. is $f(z)$ analytic in the disk?

**Attempt:** If $f(z) \ne 0$ in the disk, then $f(z) = \dfrac{f^3(z)}{f^2(z)}$ must be analytic.

Hence, any counterexample involving $f$ must be such that $f(z) = 0$ at least one point in the disk.

Any hints on how to to move forward from here?

Comment: Can you show it is still continuous at the points where $f(z)=0?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, for if $f$ was not continuous, $f^3$ won't be  continuous as well

Comment: Hint $f$ is meromorphic in the disc as the ratio of analytic function but its possible poles are only the zeroes of $f$ etc

Comment: That’s a bit vague. It’s not true that $f^3(z)$ is not continuous when $f$ is not continuous. It has something to do with $0$ specifically.

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/298951/ – duplicate question found with a Google search for “f^2 and f^3 analytic”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is the zero function then the statement is obviously true. Otherwise, $f^2$ is a nonzero holomorphic function, and so its zeros are isolated. Equivalently, the zeros of $f$ are isolated. The function $f$ is clearly analytic at all the other points of the disk, and its zeros are isolated singularities. So in order to show that $f$ is analytic at the whole disk, you just have to show that these singularities are removable. And this is indeed the case. If $f$ had a pole at such a point then so would $f^2$. If $f$ had an essential singularity then using Casorati-Weierstrass (or Picard's theorem if you know it) it is easy to show that $f^2$ would also have an essential singularity there. Both contradict the assumption that $f^2$ is holomorphic.

Comment: This is an over-kill. No need for anything as deep as Picard's theorem for this elementary  result.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I didn't write to use Picard's theorem. I wrote in brackets that IF somehow OP knows it then he might use it. Casorati-Weierstrass is more than enough, and this is taught in pretty much any complex analysis course. This should be absolutely clear. Leave alone the fact that my answer is $100$% correct.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before.